# how to make sure a php is run only from a particular page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a php file (advanced.php) which is run through ajax/javascript by a particular page, accessible only to premium users. How can I ensure on the server side that this php is run only from this particular page and no other.

I am concerned about this since there is another page available to all users which runs other php file (regular.php). It gives results in same format but are restricted. Now some user may just change the regular page to have the name advanced.php instead of regular.php in his frontend and access paid functionality for free.

How can I ensure that this doesn't happen.

Comment: Just implement some authentication if you don't want some users to access to some content

Comment: Please add a minimal coded example of where you are stuck. Without this question is way to broad and is something you could use any search engine to find resources for

Comment: Maybe you should try to check that the user has premium access in your advanced.php file and throw an error if it isn't.

Comment: Why not simply check upon reuqets to `advanced.php` that the user issuing the request (you probably know who it is through session variable) as access to that page ? (= is a premium user)

Comment: I presume people are logged in to access the advanced.php. You need to store a value in a session variable and check if this is set when the page is accessed. If it isn't set then redirect to the regular page. A problem with this method is that sessions time out so you may have to cater for that as well.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I thought about doing it though user status but was wondering if it is possible based on the page from where request came. I will do it through user status now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to block the script processing depending on where is it being loaded, you may encapsulate all the script inside a control structure.

Say you have

```
<?php my_page(); ?>
```

You could do

```
<?php
if ( $premium ) {
    // do stuff
    my_page();
    } else {
    // you could be premium ;)
    become_premium_page();
    }
?>
```

Just check if the user trying to load the page is a premium user or not.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I thought about doing it though user status but was wondering if it is possible based on the page from where request came. I will do it through user status now

Comment: You're welcome. As @Amadan mentions, it is hard to prevent the loading of the script from unexpected/unintended origins. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I ensure on the server side that this php is run only from this particular page and no other.

Don't do this. There is no reliable way to prevent this. Rather, make it so only the users with proper authorisation can access the page. This is very easy if you already have an authentication mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I thought about doing it though user status but was wondering if it is possible based on the page from where request came. I will do it through user status now